# Flash Builder and External Library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have downloaded the as3syndicationlib library from [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3syndicationlib/downloads/detail?name=xmlsyndication-.85.zip&can=2&q=), but I am having trouble adding it to my project. I dragged the folder into my project > src folder, and when I started importing the files from it (com.adobe.xml.syndication.rss.RSS20) all seemed to be fine, until I hit save. Then I started to get error that say:

`Multiple markers at this line:
-1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before 
 import.
-The import RSS20 could not be found.
-adobe
-The import rss could not be found.
-The import syndication could not be found.
-The import xml could not be found.
-91 changed lines`

I have never used an external library with Flash Builder/Flex/ActionScript3 before so I have no idea what to do. I know that this is probably very simple to do, but I am new at flash builder and flex.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jacob

**EDIT:**

I got it to work. What I was doing wrong was I was added *source code* to my project when I should have added the `xmlsyndication.swc` file to my project.

Comment: You said you dragged "The folder".  What folder is this?  What are its contents?  If you have the library as a SWC; read this blog post to see if it helps: https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/18/What-do-you-do-with-a-SWC

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to a lib folder instead of src... if you don't have a lib folder just make one.  Then right click the project in Flash Builder and hit properties, in the menu on the left select Library Path (or something like that), click the Add Folder button and type lib.  Do a clean build (Build Menu -> Clean).

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I already have a folder in my project called "libs". Should I add the library into that, or create a "lib" folder like you said in your answer?

Comment: It depends what source the library is.  If it is source code; putting it in the libs folder won't help. If it is a compiled SWC; then putting in a place other than the libs folder will require him to manually add the SWC to the library path.

Comment: @Reboog711 I got it to work! Thanks to Reboog711 - I was adding source code to my project, when I should of been adding in the "xmlsyndication.swc" file into my libs file.

Comment: Ah right, well he said library so my immediate thought was compiled library/swc not the source itself.  If adding the source itself you must be sure you replicate the package/folder structure from the original source.